# Copy rows into another sheet only if the cells1 contains "x" and cell2 contains "y"

Tags: excel, vba, google-sheets, spreadsheet

i need your help

I have a spreadsheet data with columns

Country,    Tel,    Priority, Days, name

I would like to have the rows only with Priority "high" and Days ≥ 0 copied as result on another sheet.

Any idea how can i do that?

2 Questions:

1. Can i do this without VBA codes? i mean only with Vlookup, Query ect functions?
2. If not how can i use the VBA code in spreadsheet as buttons in excel?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have a look at this http://chandoo.org/wp/2011/11/18/formula-forensics-003/

Answer (score 0):

Following is the Screenshot of sheet "Data Sheet":

[image]

Following is the Screenshot of sheet "Output":

[image]

I have the following formula in cell A2 of sheet "Output":

```
=filter('Data Sheet'!A:E,'Data Sheet'!C:C="high",'Data Sheet'!D:D>=0)
```